# PHP MySQL Query using a variable, not diplaying results, nor error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The variable I use for the query prints properly, so it is there.

```
<?php
 print $product_main["ean"]; 
//The variable is there, since it prints
?>
```

If I execute this query, it works

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM graph ;") or die(mysql_error());
```

But not with the one where I use a variable

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM graph WHERE ean IN ".$product_main["ean"]." group by DAY(created_at);") or die(mysql_error());
```

Does not work. 
I belibe the problem is in how I include the array variable into the query

```
".$product_main["ean"]."
```

How has this to be done?

Comment: Use like this `$query = ("SELECT * FROM graph WHERE ean IN ('".$product_main["ean"]."') group by DAY(created_at);")`

Comment: Why do you have `or die()` after you just create strings?

Comment: Also, you should **stop** using the old, insecure, deprecated/removed `mysql_*`-extension. It was deprecated back in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You should upgrade your driver and use parameterized queries. If `$product_main["ean"]` is an array you can't just concatenate it. Additionally, `in` in SQL uses `()` for encapsulation.

Comment: You need to execute query. You can learn how to do it here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: It should be `=` not `IN`

Comment: When you use IN, the code expects an array of values. Try casting that value as an array and try again. If it doesn't work. Supply the structure of your table, and the value of that variable.

Answer (score -1):

Ajith got it right. I was missing ('  ')

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM graph WHERE ean IN ('".$product_main["ean"]."') group by DAY(created_at);");
```

Thanks